# inner short circuit evaluation in c

Tags: c, logical-operators, short-circuiting

I know that Java and C/C++ have short circuit evaluation, i.e., in `if (a && b)`, `b` will never evaluated if `a` is not true.

But what if I have expression like `if ( (a && b) OP c )` (where `OP` is an arbitrary logical operator), will `b` evaluated if `a = false`? Thanks.

Comment: You know, the easiest thing is to just test this...

Comment: @RealSkeptic I can test it, but what does the standard say?

Comment: there is no standard this is boolean logic

Comment: The standand for Java is [the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html).

Comment: @coincoin: Only if the standard actually says so. The question is justified.

Comment: Which standard? You tagged three **different** languages. There is no language C/C++ and for Java there is no standard, but only a "standard". You better concentrate on **one**. Note: Downvotes are likely because you seem not even to have done any research on your own.

Comment: @Olaf: And the title only talks about C...

Comment: @ChristianHackl: Who reads headlines? ;-}

Comment: @ChristianHackl The title was about Java originally and currently edited to "C". I'll remove the unnecessary tags, they are only lowering the little quality there is to this question.

Answer (score 3):

C Standards say that -

> 6.5.13 Logical AND operator
>
> 4. The && operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation......
>    .If the first operand compares equal to 0, the second operand is not evaluated.

So in case `a==flase` `b` will not be evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

You will always have if **`a = false` : `a && b == 0` whatever the value of `b`**. Why would an operation done after the evaluation will change that ?

```
a b  |  a && b 
0 0  |   0
0 1  |   0
```

Comment: This is a question about Java and C++ so using a boolean as an integer might not be the best way to explain your point. By the way, `a = false` should be `a == false` or, better, `!a`

Comment: Finally, there is no absolutely rational reason for the short-circuiting, one might still want to trigger some side-effects by the evaluation of `b` without having to think about the order. At the contrary, one might also prevent this side-effect to happen is `a` is false. This is just a matter of convention, and those languages chose short-circuiting as the convention

Comment: @Dici Has nothing to do with convention. It's by definition. In Java, `a == 5 && remove(42)` is *defined* to not invoke the remove() method if a is not 5, while `a == 5 & remove(42)` is *defined* to always invoke the remove() method.

Comment: It's a convention because I can create a language which always evaluate all the expression... It's a choice of the creators of the language, not an obligation

Comment: @Dici: Then you use `bool`-only sub-expressions and bit-ops for the logical operators. This also works, but avoids short-circuit. Or you use Ada, which provides both sorts of log-ops. For most applications, shorft-circuit is the better choise or irrelevant. Note: allowing side-effects in expressions is also a "convention"

Comment: @Olaf I have never said it is not useful. I like short-circuiting and use it. I'm just  saying it is a convention, proof is that ADA both has a short-circuited and non-circuited operator

Comment: @Dici: This is not the place to discuss the pros and cons of language-features! Take it as given or write a proposal. IIRC, the next C standard is scheduled for 2017. Or write your own language,

Comment: @Olaf haha I have *never* discussed the pros and the cons, you did ! I just said it was a *convention*, because the answer seems to implie it is the only logical way to evaluate boolean expressions and it is **wrong** and someone denied it... and it is **wrong** (If anyone is not convinced this is a convention, please check this rosettacode.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). Is my point clearer now ?

Comment: @Dici: Hmm... Where did I state you did? Your comments were leading that direction, And the answer's statement is correct. The **result** of the expression will not change with the second operand. Side-effects are called like that for a reason: they are not part of the expression's result. But, ok, you are the hero.

Comment: `Why would an operation done after the evaluation will change that ?` implies it would be stupid to evaluate the right side, which is wrong since some languages do. And you did state it : `This is not the place to discuss the pros and cons of language-features! Take it as given or write a proposal`. I've never complained of anything or told I preferred one convention or another one, so this did not make sense to tell this to me

Answer (score 2):

If `a=false` then condition for `b` will not be checked so `(a && b)` is **ALWAYS false**
and the next condition depends upon the OP used if it is `&&` it will not be evaluated. If it is `||` it will be evaluated.

So

```
((a && b) OP c)
```

here if `a=false` `(a && b)` will be always false.

Comment: `&` and `|` aren't logical operators.

Comment: `&` and `|` are bitwise operators.

Comment: Sry, I am referring to C/C++. @RealSkeptic

Comment: sorry for the mistake and thanks for  telling me see the document & and | are bit wise operators https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html

Comment: @RealSkeptic: See C++ standard chapters 5.11 to 5.17. The distinction between "bit-wise" and "logical" operators is correct standard terminology in C++. The Java language specification (15.22) curiously uses the term "bitwise and logical operators".

Comment: @PiyushYawalkar Java Language Specification says that `&`, `^`, and `|` are both [bitwise **and** logical operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/expressions.html#15.22).

Comment: @Andreas: This is a nice example of why it is a bad idea to throw in multiple language tags into a question.

Comment: @RealSkeptic: Yeah. The wording in the specification leaves a lot to desire here.